# Fixing Gunicorn "no module found named index.py in import_app" error

Tags: python, docker, flask, gunicorn

I am working on Windows in a Linux Docker container. I am trying to run a Flask app via Gunicorn in a Docker container (using docker-compose). The web app keeps exiting with status 8 from the import_app function.

I've tried running command line as the administrator, I've tried to change the run command in the docker-compose file, and I've also tried running the rest of my project without it. None of these have worked.

UPDATE:
I've tried changing the port, changing the name of the file (`index.py`), reinstalling the Docker image for Python, pruning my old docker containers, adding Python path in the docker-compose, and

docker-compose.yml :

```
version: '3'
services:
    web:
        build: .
        command: gunicorn "index:app" -b 0.0.0.0:8080
        ports:
            - "8888:8080"
        volumes:
            - .:/code
        depends_on:
            - redis
    redis:
        image: redis
```

And then the console traceback:

```
web_1    | [2018-12-19 20:36:50 +0000] [8] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
web_1    | Traceback (most recent call last):
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
web_1    |     worker.init_process()
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
web_1    |     self.load_wsgi()
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
web_1    |     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
web_1    |     self.callable = self.load()
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
web_1    |     return self.load_wsgiapp()
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
web_1    |     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
web_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
web_1    |     __import__(module)
web_1    | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'index'
web_1    | [2018-12-19 20:36:50 +0000] [8] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 8)
web_1    | [2018-12-19 20:36:50 +0000] [1] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
web_1    | [2018-12-19 20:36:50 +0000] [1] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to         boot.
flaskpython_web_1 exited with code 3
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV FLASK_APP=index.py

# copy current directory into working directory
COPY . /code
WORKDIR /code

# install python packages
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

expose 8080

CMD ["gunicorn", "index:app", "-b", "0.0.0.0:8080"]
```

Finally the structure of the project:

```
|docker-compose.yml
|Dockerfile
|index.py
|requirements.txt
```

The expected result is that webserver doesn't crash or exit with all the workers exiting. I want it to recognize that index is my entry point to the rest of the project.

Comment: What does your `Dockerfile` look like?

Comment: @nebuler I've added to my original question to include the Dockerfile

Comment: Does it also fail if you try running it using the `Dockerfile` alone?

Comment: @nebuler yes it does not work no matter how I run it. Works on my co-workers computer, but fails the same way on another co-workers computer. We reviewed the code today and it's all the exact same.

Comment: Do both coworkers have windows OS? Also, look at my answer below.

Comment: Both coworkers are on Windows computers (along with myself). Everyone is using Linux containers. I've also tried running these from both command prompt and Windows Powershell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be specific to docker for windows. Look [here](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/2548) for a discussion about it. In short, docker-machine mounts `C:\users\[USERNAME]` by default, so mounting a location that lives somewhere else won't work - it will result in the bind mount being empty.

As for the solution, you have a few of options:

- Remove the volume option from docker-compose file. This should be ok since you are already adding everything you need to the image in the `Dockerfile`.
- Put your project somewhere in your home directory, `C:\users\[USERNAME]`, and run everything from there.
- Go to docker settings and set the shared drives to the ones you need, probably **C**. More details [here](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#shared-drives).

Comment: I had my C:/ drive shared the entire time, but removing the volumes did the trick. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Gunicorn will look for `index.py` on the `PYTHONPATH` inside the container. Try setting the `PYTHONPATH` as an environment variable in your `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'
services:
    web:
        build: .
        command: gunicorn "index:app" -b 0.0.0.0:8080
        environment:
            PYTHONPATH: '/code'
        ...
```

Comment: This did not appear to make any change to the output. Still hitting the same error. I'm going to try to explore more solutions with changing how different paths are specified.

Comment: @AndrewSamuelson worth also trying to pass the PYTHONPATH directly in the gunicorn command: `gunicorn "index:app" -b 0.0.0.0:8080 --pythonpath "/code"`

Comment: didn't quite work. It might be a problem with my install of Gunicorn. If I manage to find the solution I'll make sure to update here.